# Retrieve a numeric value from a json file a match it within an if statement in a dynamic way

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, if-statement

Achievement: I'm building a radio announcer feed in a section of my website.

Problem: I have to display a different announcer based on specific time of the day and day of the week. I was able to create an ajax call (jquery) and display an image (and some other information) in a static way, based on the position of each object of my json file.

Question: Is there an easier (and faster way) to find the exact object and match it with time and day in order to display only one object and avoid to write a bunch of code?

Code (to better explain better my problem):

HTML

```
<div id="radioOnAir"></div>
```

JQUERY

Here's my problem: I'm uploading a bunch of code. As you can see I call each marker with its position in the array (number), but, ideally, I would like to create a function to find a value between two values (like I did for the if statement) within the markers and then match it and display in my IF statement.

The code I created so far is:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "announcers.json",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(markers) {

                var date = new Date();
                var day = date.getDay();
                var secs = date.getSeconds() + (60 * (date.getMinutes() + (60 * date.getHours())));

                if (day==1 || day==2 || day==3 || day==4 || day==5) {
                    if (secs >= 19800 && secs <= 35999) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[4].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[4].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                        if (markers[4].announcer_facebook != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[4].announcer_facebook+'"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[4].announcer_twitter != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[4].announcer_twitter+'"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[4].announcer_mail != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="mailto:'+markers[4].announcer_mail+'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 36000 && secs <= 53999) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[0].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[0].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                        if (markers[0].announcer_facebook != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[0].announcer_facebook+'"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[0].announcer_twitter != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[0].announcer_twitter+'"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[0].announcer_mail != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="mailto:'+markers[0].announcer_mail+'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 54000 && secs <= 71999) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[3].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[3].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                        if (markers[3].announcer_facebook != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[3].announcer_facebook+'"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[3].announcer_twitter != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="'+markers[3].announcer_twitter+'"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                        if (markers[3].announcer_mail != null) {
                            $('.left').append('<a href="mailto:'+markers[3].announcer_mail+'"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>');
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (secs >= 72000 && secs <= 86399) {
                    if (day==1 || day==2) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[10].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[10].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    else if (day==3 || day==4 || day==5) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[8].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[8].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                }
                if (day==6) {
                    if (secs >= 25200 && secs <= 32399) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[1].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[1].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 32400 && secs <= 50399) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[6].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[6].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 50400 && secs <= 71999) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[2].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[2].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                }
                if (day==7) {
                    if (secs >= 32400 && secs <= 50399) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[7].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[7].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 50400 && secs <= 71999) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[9].announcer_photo+'">'+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[9].announcer_name+'</div></div>');
                    }
                    else if (secs >= 72000 && secs <= 79199) {
                        $('#radioOnAir').prepend('<img src="images/'+markers[5].announcer_photo+'">')+'<div class="left">'+'<div class="onAir">on air</div>'+'<div>'+markers[5].announcer_name+'</div></div>';
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });

JSON file:

    [
  {
    "announcer_id": "18",
    "announcer_time_start": "05:30:00",
    "announcer_time_end": "10:59:59",
    "announcer_photo": "Bob and Di.jpg",
    "announcer_name": "Bob and Diana",
    "announcer_facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_rss": "http://923thedock.com/bobndiana/",
    "announcer_mail": "bwallace@larche.com",
    "announcer_weekday": "1,2,3,4,5"
  },
  {
    "announcer_id": "17",
    "announcer_time_start": "09:00:00",
    "announcer_time_end": "11:59:59",
    "announcer_photo": "Bob Wallace.jpg",
    "announcer_name": "Bob Wallace",
    "announcer_facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_rss": "http://923thedock.com/bobndiana/",
    "announcer_mail": "bwallace@larche.com",
    "announcer_weekday": ""
  },
  {
    "announcer_id": "3",
    "announcer_time_start": "14:00:00",
    "announcer_time_end": "17:59:59",
    "announcer_photo": "don-s.jpg",
    "announcer_name": "Don Vail",
    "announcer_facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_rss": "http://923thedock.com/announcers/don-vail/",
    "announcer_mail": "dvail@larche.com",
    "announcer_weekday": "1,2,3,4,5"
  }
]
```

Any suggestion?

I'm trying this approach:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
                var a = markers[i].announcer_time_start.split(':');
                var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);

                var b = markers[i].announcer_time_end.split(':');
                var secondsb = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]); 

                // console.log(seconds, secondsb, markers[i].announcer_name, markers[i].announcer_weekday, markers[i].announcer_photo);
                if (markers[i].announcer_time_start >= secs && markers[i].announcer_time_end <= secs) {
                    console.log(markers[i].announcer_time_start);
                }
```

How can I find a value between two number and then display only that value within a Json array?

Comment: you can simply iterate over your json response & then check the conditions

Comment: To say the above a little more verbosely, iterate over the json object, check to see the announcer_time_start is less than "now" and announcer_time_end is greater than "now".

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but it would appear to be easier if you simply formatted the current time in the same format as your data, rather than trying to use the number of seconds. There are a lot of questions on SO about how to format dates and times. It's not clear what the rest of your code is doing (the JSON you show doesn't seem to have any relation to the indexes used in the code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses moment.js, because dates in Javascript are terrible.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "announcers.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false,
    success: function(markers) {
      var momentNow = moment();
      $.each(markers,function(i, val){
        $arrDays = val.announcer_weekday.split(",");  //create array of the weekdays
        if($arrDays.indexOf(momentNow.day())) {                   //is one of those days today?
          var arrStartTimes = val.announcer_time_start.split(":");  //get the start time into an array
          var arrEndTimes = val.announcer_time_end.split(":");      //get the end time into an array
          var stime = moment().hour(arrStartTimes[0]).minute(arrStartTimes[1]).second(arrStartTimes[2]);  //set the date today, then override the hour/minute/second
          var etime = moment().hour(arrEndTimes[0]).minute(arrEndTimes[1]).second(arrEndTimes[2]);        //same here for end time
          if(momentNow.isSameOrAfter(stime) && momentNow.isSameOrBefore(etime) ) {  //the start time is now or later and the end time is now or before
            alert(val.announcer_name + " should be on the air right now");
          } else {
            alert(val.announcer_name + " should not be on the air right now");
          }
        } //if($arrDays.indexOf(momentNow.day())) {
      }); //$.each(markers,function(i, val){
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will give a try it now and I will let you know as soon!! I'm gonna add my solution too, even if it doesn't work properly

Comment: Great, it works! By the way, if you have a chance, could you tell me where I was wrong in my code? Do I have to iterate in another different time the days of the week?

Comment: Your code wasn't wrong, just different.  Getting the time difference between dates is a huge pain, unless you use moment.js (or a half dozen other libraries like it) to do the heavy lifting for you.  Moment.js and the fact that I'm using $.each() from jQuery are the only major differences between what you wrote and what I did..

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you.  If you want to reference the announcer's data use the following (in my code) val.announcer_name, val.annoucer_time_start, etc

Comment: yeah, the $arrDays.indexOf was the key to solving my problem. Thank you for your hint. By the way, moment.js is a good idea and it makes sense using it to shorten the process. Both ideas were good, but you gave me the hint which solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out the part of the second (from a particular hour of a day), but not the day of the week:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "announcers.json",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(markers) {

            var date = new Date();
            var day = date.getDay();
            var secs = date.getSeconds() + (60 * (date.getMinutes() + (60 * date.getHours())));
            console.log(day, secs);

            for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
                // console.log(markers[i].announcer_weekday);
                var a = markers[i].announcer_time_start.split(':');
                var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);

                var b = markers[i].announcer_time_end.split(':');
                var secondsb = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]); 

                console.log(seconds, secondsb, markers[i].announcer_name, markers[i].announcer_weekday, markers[i].announcer_photo);
                if (seconds <= secs && secondsb >= secs) {
                    console.log(markers[i].announcer_name);
                }


            }
        }
    });
```

This is because the markers.announcer_weekday is an array so I changed my json file in order to create an array in one of the value within the array:

```
{
    "announcer_id": "21",
    "announcer_time_start": "18:00:00",
    "announcer_time_end": "23:59:59",
    "announcer_photo": "Mark Hendrie.jpg",
    "announcer_name": "Mark Hendrie",
    "announcer_facebook": "http://www.facebook.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_twitter": "http://www.twitter.com/923thedock",
    "announcer_rss": "",
    "announcer_mail": "mhendrie@larche.com",
    "announcer_weekday": [3,4,5]
  }
```

But in this way I'm not able to retrieve any value from the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
                // console.log(markers[i].announcer_weekday);
                var a = markers[i].announcer_time_start.split(':');
                var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);

                var b = markers[i].announcer_time_end.split(':');
                var secondsb = (+b[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+b[1]) * 60 + (+b[2]); 
                var dayoftheweek = markers[i].announcer_weekday;
                console.log(seconds, secondsb, markers[i].announcer_name, markers[i].announcer_weekday, markers[i].announcer_photo);
                if (day == dayoftheweek) {
                    if (seconds <= secs && secondsb >= secs) {
                        console.log(markers[i].announcer_name);
                    }
                }
            }
```

How can I check a single element of an array like that "announcer_weekday": [3,4,5] with my current day and then match it with the time of the day?